# POI XSSF class Throws NullPointerException when createCell or setCellValue to empty row in existing Excel

Tags: java, excel, selenium, webdriver, apache-poi

POI XSSF class Throws NullPointerException when createCell or setCellValue to empty row in existing Excel

If Existing Excel's row is fill with data then .. below code will execute and override the data..
CODE :

```
            rowsline= sourceSheet.getRow(RowNo);
            rowsline.createCell(CellNo);
            rowsline.getCell(CellNo).setCellValue(DataValue);
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            srcBook.write(outputStream);
```

ERROR :

```
      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
      at Source_Program.SourceProgram.SetDataInExcel(SourceProgram.java:146)
```

Comment: which is line 146?

Comment: 146 line - rowsline.createCell(CellNo);

Comment: well in that case `rowsline= sourceSheet.getRow(RowNo);` failed

Comment: No.. it's working.. createCell() is function that returns the Nullpointer.. when Excel Cell is empty....

Comment: don't know how to handle it .. when excel Cell is filled with data.. then code override data.. and execute program successfully ... NullpointerException only occurred when Cell is Empty

Comment: my code `Cell cell = sh.getRow(1).getCell(cellNum);
    
    if (cell != null) {
     cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
    }`

Comment: M doing it with XSSF class - poi-3.15-beta2 and it's not working...

Comment: Done ... Firstly need to check whether row is empty or not... is row is empty and need to add new row and after that.. need to cell and set data... Thanks Scary Wombat...

Comment: Well done.  Glad it works for you.